# Description list of bullet points with less margin

Tags: spacing, lists, description

I am using the following

```
\begin{description}[font=\textendash\enskip\scshape\bfseries]
\item [ item1] blabla
\item [ item2] bla2bla2
\end{description}
```

but I want less margin between 2 items. I found an easy way to do it for the itemize tag but I want to use the description tag. Is there an easy way to do it?

**Edit** I am using the moderncv template, my document looks like the following

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage[scale=.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}`
```

Comment: please extend your code snippet to small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You mean less vertical spacing between items?

Comment: since you use `enumitem`, change `itemsep` and  `parsep` (if necessary)  or use `nosep`. read documentation for `enumitem` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `itemsep`. Either use `noitemsep` or `itemsep=0pt`(not the same result). I replaced `\enskip` with a thinspace, as I think it looks better. Note you need a sans font which has bold smallcaps, which is not the case of the default  Latin Modern Sans:

```
\documentclass[12pt, sans, a4paper ]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=.85, showframe]{geometry}
 \usepackage{enumitem} %

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[font=\textendash\,\scshape\bfseries, noitemsep]
\item [ item1] blabla
\item [ item2] bla2bla2
\end{description}

\begin{description}[font=\textendash\,\scshape\bfseries, itemsep = 0pt]
\item [ item1] blabla
\item [ item2] bla2bla2
\end{description}

\begin{description}[font=\textendash\,\scshape\bfseries]
\item [ item1] blabla
\item [ item2] bla2bla2
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]